# atmega16 serial communication not working (both uart_send and uart_receive)

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, avr, uart

I'm trying to communicate between a BLE using `Atmega16` with android app(Just to send a character and receive it back).

I'm able to transfer data between BLE with arduino and app but when i'm using atmega16 micro-controller it's not working. When i'm trying to send a character and recieve it back some characters are getting back exactly (`0 to 9,q,w,r,t,y,u,p,z,s,x,v,:,^,=,?,;`), but others are not.

I think the problem is with my baud rate and CPU frequency. I tried many combinations but none of them are returning whole charcters back exactly.
These are my uart initialization and Interrupt functions

I've used CPU frequency `14.7456MHz` and Baud rate `230.5k`. I tried using baud rate `9600` at `8Mhz` frequency but for these values random garbage values are coming back.

```
#define F_CPU 14745600UL
#define BAUDRATE 230500UL
#define BAUD_PRESCALE ((F_CPU / (BAUDRATE * 16))) - 1

void uart_init() {
    UBRRL = (unsigned char) (BAUD_PRESCALE);
    UBRRH = (unsigned char) (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8);

    UCSRB = (1 << RXEN) | (1 << TXEN) | (1 << RXCIE);
    UCSRC = (1 << URSEL) | (1 << UCSZ0) | (1 << UCSZ1);

    // Need to disable JTAG twice. Read spec sheet for details.
    // http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/618701#comment-618701
    MCUCSR = (1 << JTD);
    MCUCSR = (1 << JTD);
}        

ISR(USART_RXC_vect) {    
    uint8_t c = UDR;        
    UDR = c;
    PORTA = c;
}
```

Any help!!

Comment: Are you sure the frame format (parity, stop bits) is matching?

Comment: As pointed out by @Rev1.0 you are not setting parity and stop bits. If the same code worked the other device match the other side parameters by default.

Comment: I've used no parity bit and 1 stop bit in a frame. With which this frame format should match with? (i'm new to this)

Comment: Both side of communication have to use the same frame. Posted code is not setting those params: what are default value for atmega16?

Comment: [This post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/61197) should help you.

Comment: All characters (a-z) and numbers(0-9) are getting back exactly when i'm using reserved parity. But i now got a new problem. In the above code i'm setting the recieved character value to PORTA. I've connected 8 LED's to PORTA. When i send a charcter that character is receiving back exactly but LED's are not glowing accordingly. What might be the problem?

Comment: LEDs backwards.  No Vcc on LEDs, No ground on LEDs. Port pin selection not configured as GPIO.  Port direction not set  to output.  Port pullup resistors not selected.  Port pulldown resistors not selected.   Someone with access to the the hardware and test equipment will have to fix your new problem, we cannot do it.

Comment: @manishreddy : If your problem is now solved you should post an answer to your own question; it is not clear from your comment what you have done, and comments are not the place for answers in any case.  The trouble you are having with your debug technique is an entirely different issue.

Comment: Check the hardware, use a scope to verify signal quality and transmission parameters.

Comment: Actually i'm still getting the same above problem. Above mentioned characters are echoing back at every time. But this time the other characters like 'a','c','h' etc are some times echoing back properly and some times not. I am now using reserved parity settings. Don't know what to do?

Comment: How do we get to know that this is the right frequency for doing operations

Comment: I figured out that i haven't set the baud rate of BLE properly. Now, i have changed both ends to 9600bps, 1MHz frequency, 1 stob bit and no parity. Now i'm getting better results.For example, if i send 'a' then i'm getting '01100001' sometimes and '11100001' sometimes. '01100001' is the actual ascii of 'a'. Similarly there are slight differences between what i recieve and what i send. I checked that error for my baud rate and frequncy is 7%. But if i change frequency to where error is very less, i'm getting worse results than this.I'm using internal oscillaor.Can this be a reason for my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to change fuse bits not only when using external crystal/resonator, but we also have to change fuse bits when we are using internal RC oscillator. The default configuration of fuse bits is for frequency 1Mhz. For different frequencies of internal RC oscillator we need to set the fuse bits accordingly. This [fuse bit calculator](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc) will be helpful.

How to set fuse bits is explained in this [blog](http://treehouseprojects.ca/fusebits/).

I don't know earlier that we have to set different fuse bit configurations for different internal frequencies also.

Finally i solved my problem with your support. Next i have to transfer strings and much more.

Thank you all.

Comment: Now i'm using baud rate 9600bps and frequency 4Mhz for 0% error. I've set fuse bits according to 4Mhz internal oscillator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing it in Atmel studio. It has terminal window exstension (it worked on 6.0 version, on 7.0 I don't know now).

If you're not using Atmel studio, than open some terminal and listen what's coming. If you are getting dummy data, it means you haven't configured fuse bits properly as is answered upper.

If you're using Atmel studio, I suggest use some STK500 like programmer and integrate it in Atmel studio. Program devices from there. It's more comfortable and fuse bit settings is easy from there.

I see you're using 14745600 hz oscillator. You have to set fuse bits for External high frequency oscillator ready.

If you want to disable JTAG it's possible to disable it from fuse bits.